# Why is Angular form reloading the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-ng-click, ng-submit

I have the following forms, on the same page:

```
<form ng-submit="actionA()">
    <input type="text">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<form ng-submit="actionB()">
    <input type="text">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

At the moment, when I submit either form, the page reloads. How do I prevent that? I know I could use event.preventDefault() but I'd like to know if there's a plain Angular solution.

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/form

Comment: I think its because you are using the type='submit', just use type='button'

Comment: look for errors on your page. do you have a defined ngApp, and ngController, and is it in scope for your forms?

Comment: ngApp, ngController, all good, no errors.

Answer (score 9):

Make sure you import **FormsModule** from **@angular/forms** in the module containing your component because without it your form on submit will keep refreshing the page and failing silently without logging anything to the console.

Comment: Please use markdown for code in this format `FormsModule `

Comment: nice, did the job.

Answer (score 1):

According to Angular's [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/form) it should not be reloading the page

> Since the role of forms in client-side Angular applications is different than in classical roundtrip apps, it is desirable for the browser not to translate the form submission into a full page reload that sends the data to the server. Instead some javascript logic should be triggered to handle the form submission in an application-specific way.
>
> For this reason, Angular prevents the default action (form submission to the server) unless the  element has an action attribute specified.

Here's the [example](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSubmit#example) given by them that doesn't reload.

I have a feeling your angular app is not bootstrapped or the bindings are not bound.

Answer (score 0):

this stopped my paage from reloading

```html
<button  mat-raised-button color="accent" type="button" (click)="addFabric(formTemplate.value)">submit</button>
```

Comment: check my answer here for more explanations https://stackoverflow.com/a/62002031/12955928