# ngSubmit refreshes the page in Angular 2 form

Tags: angular, typescript

I am using Angular2 template for creating a form.

When i click on button, the pages refreshes.

My validations are working fine.

How can i stop page refresh when user clicks on button?

Following is HTML I am using:-

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title">Add Employee</h3>
        {{model | json}}
        {{EName.errors | json}}
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body">  
        <form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(empForm)" #empForm="ngForm" autocomplete="off" novalidate>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="EmployeeName">Employee Name</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="EmployeeName" placeholder="Employee Name" required [(ngModel)]="model.EName" name="EName" #EName="ngModel" ngControl="Ename" #EName="EName" >
            <div *ngIf="EName.touched && EName.errors" >
                <div *ngIf="EName.errors.required"  class="alert alert-danger">
                    Employee Name is required
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="Age">Age</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Age" name="Age" placeholder="Age" [(ngModel)]="model.Age" ngControl="Age">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">            
            <label for="Sex">Sex</label>
            <div class="d-block">
                <label class="radio-inline">
                    <input type="radio" name="sex" id="Male" value="0" (click)="model.Sex=$event.target.value"> Male
                </label>
                <label class="radio-inline">
                    <input type="radio" name="sex" id="Female" value="1" (click)="model.Sex=$event.target.value"> Female
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="DOJ">Date of Joining</label>
            <datepicker [(ngModel)]="model.DOJ" name="DOJ"></datepicker>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="Salary">Salary</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="Salary" placeholder="Salary" [(ngModel)]="model.Salary" name="Salary">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="Designation">Designation</label>
            <select id="Designation" name="designation" class="form-control" required [(ngModel)]="model.Designation" name="designation" #desig="ngForm" ngControl="Designation">
                <option value="" selected>-- Select  --</option>
                <option *ngFor="let designation of designations" value="{{ designation.id }}"> 
                    {{designation.name}} 
                </option>
            </select>
            <div [hidden]="desig.valid || desig.pristine" class="alert alert-danger">
                Please select a proper designation.
            </div>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" [disabled] ="!empForm.form.valid">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 89):

Make sure you import **FormsModule** from **@angular/forms** in the module containing your component because without it your form on submit will keep refreshing the page and failing silently without logging anything to the console.

```
import { NgModule }           from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule }       from '@angular/common';

/*make sure you import it here*/
import { FormsModule }        from '@angular/forms';

 @NgModule({
  /*and add it to the imports array here*/
  imports:      [ FormsModule,  CommonModule],
  declarations: [ YourFormComponent ],
  exports:      [],
  providers:    [],
})

export class FeatureModule{ }
```

Answer (score 82):

it refreshes because there is an error in `onSubmit` handler..
use `event.PreventDefault();` in the `onSubmit` :

```
 <form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(empForm, $event)" ... >


public onSubmit(empForm: any, event: Event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  .... rest of your code
}
```

also you can just check the console output to debug the error
... make sure to mark the `preserve log` option

[image: preserve log checked in devtools]

Comment: this bug happens under rare circumstances, it seems. Certainly *not* if the input fields are empty by default.

Comment: This solution, as far as I can tell, is not compatible with the AoT compiler. I tried every which way I could think of, but always receive `Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target.`.

Comment: Even if I have implemented `event.preventDefault()` the onSubmit() function causes page refresh/postback. any idea why?

Comment: The 'preserve log' saved me. The page refreshes so fast I didn't see there was an error while submitting

Answer (score 16):

Use instead:

```ts
<button type="button"
```

The reload is caused by the default submit behavior of the browser.

Comment: You are right. I can change button type to button, But how can we do it with button type submit. Actually I am learning angular2. :)

Comment: @Saroj onclick="return false;"

Comment: @asdf_enel_hak `(click)="false"` would do the same but I don't know if Angulars `ngSubmit` is called then. I'd expect this would need `(click)="form.submit();false"` or something but `type="button"` is way easier.

Comment: I seen many examples on internet (https://github.com/DeborahK/ngconf2016/blob/master/MovieHunter/app/movies/movie-edit-template.component.html). We don't require to use false nor we require to do anything special.

Comment: What do you suggest instead? And what's the problem with `type="button"`?

Comment: Nothing. I want to learn how to use ngSubmit and why my code with ngSubmit reloading complete page

Comment: I guess the new forms module just doesn't catch and suppress the submit event like previous versions.

Comment: I had this problem. The approach with calling `event.preventDefault()` did not make any difference. However, I tried another proposed solution -- move the method call from the form (that is, onSubmit) onto the button itself + changing button type from `submit` to `button` did the trick.

Answer (score 6):

Update 2019/2018 -
If this is happening to you on any recent version of Angular (I'm currently on 7), it's not due to a `<button type="submit"...>`, in-fact, that's perfectly fine, you can keep that.  You can also keep the `(submit)` event on your `<form>` element.
You likely have an error somewhere else which is causing Angular to not act as intended.

- Please make sure you have included the `FormsModule` or `ReactiveFormsModule` if you're using reactive forms.
- Please make sure you don't have errors in your console (click f12 then navigate to `Console`)

Angular will not refresh the page if you have properly instantiated your Form.

Comment: Confirmed in 2022 (on Angular 11). I had an error but I didn't see it because I didn't have the "preserve log" in my console. Activate it, see the error, fix the error, and the form will stop reloading the page.

Comment: When using ReactiveFormsModule, make sure to actually use the formGroup directive directly on the form element to avoid refreshing the page. I had really small form where I didn't even have formGroup at all and used a single formControl directly on the input instead - angular form logic didn't trigger that way and page was reloading on submit. Simply adding even empty formGroup on the form element solved the problem.

Answer (score 5):

This worked and stopped the whole page from reloading:

1. I changed the button type from "submit" to "button"
2. I introduced a (click)= `submitValues()` inside the button props like
   this :

   *submit*

This stopped the page from reloading, I hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

**Refreshes the page in Angular 2 form:**

Change button type from **"submit"** to **button**, no change can reflect.

Solution:

**form module** has to imported in your corresponding module. Because <**form**> without form module, consider as html form.So that form gets refresh.

```
<form (submit)="onSubmit()">
   <input type="text" name="firstName"/>
   <button type="submit">submit</button>
</form>
```

Button **type** with **submit** only able to trigger the form **onsubmit()**

Answer (score 1):

You should be import FormsModule on the "app.module.ts". like this:

```
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

@NgModule({
  imports:[ FormsModule ]
```

About the action (click) on the , there is a problem because, if a user click on the button more than once, your code will submit the same times at the API and the Database. In my opinion is better you use the action(ngSubmit) at the  for submit only when the validation of form is done.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing this same issue, onsubmit of my reactive form the page was getting reloaded.
I found that I had assigned value to my reactive form control using '='.
I changed the assignment using `setValue()` and it resolved my issue:

```
this.formName.controls.fieldName.setValue(value);
```

Answer (score 0):

**The same thing happened to me, I did not declare the page in the page module. after declaring the page into the page module, it fixed my problem.**

```
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';

import { FormPage } from './formPage';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule
  ],
 declarations: [FormPage]
```

Answer (score -1):

User from onSubmit handler in the onSubmit :

```
<form id="..." (ngSubmit)="onSubmit($event)" ... >

public onSubmit(event: Event) {
  .... rest of your code
}
```

Answer (score -1):

i solve this problem by using

```
<button type="button">Submit</button>
```

instead of

```
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
```

submit keyword is responsible for page refreshing.