# Why the page is reloading after using a post to upload a file? (Angular + Spring Boot )

Tags: java, angular, typescript, spring-boot, api

File Uploading is working but the app is reloading after receiving the response from the backend. 
Angular Code  
HTML

```
<input hidden="true" accept="text/pdf, .pdf" type="file" #pdfInput id="report"
                       (change)="validateFile($event)">
<mat-card class="reportName">
   <input readonly matInput name="fileHidden" formControlName="pdfFile">
</mat-card>

<button class="mat-raised-button" [disabled]="this.uploadReport.invalid" (click)="saveReport()">Upload Document</button>
```

TS

```
saveReport() {
    console.log(this.uploadReport.value.category);
    this.reportService.saveReport(this.uploadReport.value.category, this.uploadFile).subscribe((val) => {
      console.log(val);
    })
  }

saveReport(category :string, dataFile : FormData): Observable<ApiResponse> {
    return this.http.post<ApiResponse>(this.ROOT_URL + '/report/' + category  , dataFile, {reportProgress: true, responseType: 'json'});
  }
```

Spring boot

```
@PostMapping("/{category}")
    public ResponseEntity<Response<String>> saveReport(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile multipartFile,
                                                       @PathVariable String category) throws IOException 
        return ResponseEntity.ok(reportService.saveReport(category, multipartFile));
    }
```

Comment: is your HTML code wrapped into a `<form>` element? If so, the answers here might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39203428/ngsubmit-refreshes-the-page-in-angular-2-form

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the app is reloading due to receiving the response from the backend. Is your uploading button the only button in a form? if then try to prevent submitting behaviour of the form:

> <button (click)="saveReport(); $event.preventDefault()">

or

> Add type='button' to that button. A button without any defined type in a form acts like a submit button

Comment: If I remove the file upload it works fine.  both didn't work. I'm using 3 buttons.

Comment: @Ezra what if change those buttons to `divs with (click) events`?

Comment: the same thing happens :(

Comment: Weird, did u solve the prob? How did you find the app reloading right after getting the server response?

Comment: I found the problem,
I was saving the uploaded file inside the angular project folder. So the angular app is re-compiling when the project folder gets updated. So I changed the location. @WhiteLink Thank You :)

Comment: Wow this is unexpectable

Comment: @Savidya Did you solve this problem? Everytime I save an image in my Assets/images my page reloads.